# How to add custom actions to yii2 kartik CheckBoxColumn

Tags: gridview, kartik-v

I have a kartik gridview , and one column is a checkbox ,when i click the check box it should update the database also.
my code is

```
[
    'class' => '\kartik\grid\CheckboxColumn',
    'attribute' => 'videoRecieved',
    'pageSummary' => 'Total',
    'vAlign' => 'middle',
    'width' => '50px',
    'header' => "Video Recieved",
    'checkboxOptions' => [
        'onclick' => 'js:updateCheck(this.value, this.checked,1)',
    ],
]
```

Then in the updateCheck() i am sending the values to the db.But i couldn't find the reference of that particular row, then only i can send the value to the db and update that particular row.
And also it should check by default when the value in the db is 1.so i added

```
'checkboxOptions' => function($model) {
        if($model->uploaded){
           return ['checked' => true];
        }else{
           return ['checked' => false];
        }
     },
```

By doing this i can find the value of the checkbox is the primary key id from the db, so i get the reference id for that row.But i couldn't add the onclick event.
How can i add the onclick event to the second checkboxOptions.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To get an array of the selected rows in Kartik's gridView with a checkbox column

```
let selected_rows = $('#w0').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
```

`selected_rows` will then contain an array with all primary keys of the rows in the gridView.